# Scroll jumps to the bottom of the page after resizing text

Tags: javascript, css, angular, infinite-loop, font-size

I have an Angular 8 project, which receives list of products from the server. Since the number of products per user might be very large, I'm making request and displaying to user only first 20 items, but when he reaches the bottom of the container, I'm uploading 20 more items. For scroll detection I'm using [infinite-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll) library. Everything worked fine until I've added another [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-fittext), that autoresizes product title to fit container width. After adding it, scroll started automatically jump to the end of the container (to the latest uploaded item) and because of that it triggers uploading of another bunch of additional items. Before adding autoresize, users were staying on the same place (at the end of the first 20 items).

I have already tried next steps:

1. Removed infinite-scroll and wrote my own method to detect when user
   reaches end of container to upload new items. Result: same behavior
   with scroll drop.
2. Removed fittext library and wrote my own directive to resize text
   label. Result: same behavior with scroll jump.
3. Tried to switch overflow on container to hidden to prevent scroll,
   tried to change scrollTop value.

Nothing helps. Scroll is still jumping to the end each time new items are loaded. But when I'm removing autoresize feature - everything works fine, except I don't have autoresize..

Maybe someone had similar issue or have any ideas about how to prevent that scroll jump? 
Thanks!

This is my html:

```
 <div class="prizes__wrapper" *ngIf="viewModel.prizes.items.length > 0" infinite-scroll [scrollWindow]="false"
      (scrolled)="scrollDown(this.viewModel.prizes, 0)">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="outer__wrapper" *ngFor="let prize of viewModel.prizes.items; let i=index; first as isFirst">
          <div class="inner__wrapper">
            <div class="prize">
              <div class="image-wrapper">
                <div class="prize__date">
                  {{'claim_page_won_title' | translate:(prize.created | date:'mediumDate')}}
                </div>
                <div class="prize__image" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + prize.machineImage + ')' }">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="prize-controls">
                <div class="title-container">
                  <p class="title" appTextFit>{{prize.prizeShortName}}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Styles for container with overflow:

```
    .prizes__wrapper
      height: 100%
      overflow-y: scroll
      scrollbar-width: none
      -ms-overflow-style: none
```

Comment: can you provide one demo in stackblitz?

Comment: Problematic. Since I'll need to rewrite a lot. I can't show any production code, requests and data due to contract with client. I suppose that the problem is change detection. That  Angular updates the page again after text resizes and that's why it's dropped to the end of the page...

Answer (score 0):

Adding trackBy on ngFor element helped to fix that issue.

```
      <div class="machine" *ngFor="let machine of viewModel.machines; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
```